# Android resource compilation failed v3.3

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I just updated my android studio to version 3.3 and Im getting this error [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB8Lq.png). I noticed that the problem here may be the word "table" above the redline so I tryied to change this line of code to this `<item name="table" type="id"/>` but always returns in the running of the project.Any help please?
I also have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2ScY.png) on the top of the page

Comment: show the original file not the generated one

Comment: what do you mean? @VivekMishra

Comment: read the warning message being shown on top in your first screenshot

Comment: @VivekMishra you mean that ? http://prntscr.com/m7f52i

Comment: I didn't meant this but from the image that you just posted read the 12th line from the top and you will understand your real issue

Comment: " <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty " ?@VivekMishra

Comment: yes this one. Search for this and you should get your answer

Comment: @VivekMishra Already did that man. As I said to my first question ,I changed this http://prntscr.com/m7f8px to this "  <item name="table" type="id"/>  " .But when im running the project it always returns as  "   <item name="table" type="id">table</item>  "

Comment: Post your ids.xml file code

Comment: oh i see,it fixed,thanks

Comment: Also remember not to post your code as images, always paste your code here and format it

Comment: @VivekMishra I will do it next time!